# SQL Server - Cast specific string date format to date datatype

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

I am trying to insert data into a DATE column in Microsoft SQL using the code below:

```
INSERT INTO sde.AMD_NDVI_CAT (OBJECTID, Name, ImageDate) 
VALUES (6199,'VI_{960D55A4-EEFD-45DD-80FD-81B5113C43D5}_20220122T090159', CAST('20220122T090159' AS DATE))
```

What I get is:

```
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.
```

The data to be inserted into `ImageDate` column has the format `YYYYMMDDTHHMMSS`. I did not find this format on the Microsoft webpage (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15). How can I convert it to date in order to be inserted into the table?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `date` suggests you don't care about time:

```
SELECT CONVERT(date, LEFT('20220122T090159', 8));
```

If you need time too, it gets quite ugly.

```
DECLARE @funny_string char(15) = '20220122T090159';

SELECT TRY_CONVERT(datetime, 
  LEFT(@funny_string, 8) + ' ' 
  + STUFF(STUFF(RIGHT(@funny_string, 6), 3, 0, ':'),6, 0, ':'));
```

Comment: Thanks, but I also need the time to be kept.

Comment: @Litwos If you need time then you need to change your data type in the table, since `date` doesn't store time.

Comment: Perhaps slightly simpler than using `LEFT/RIGHT` is to just use a 3rd `STUFF()` to remove the `T` and add the required space between date and time - `TRY_CONVERT(datetime, STUFF(STUFF(STUFF(@funny_string, 14, 0, ':'), 12, 0, ':'), 9, 1, ' '))`, (if not simpler, slightly shorter) but still ugly and the resulting string is exactly the same, so entirely personal preference.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to capture both date and time, then we can use `TRY_CONVERT` along with a bit of string manipulation:

```sql
SELECT TRY_CONVERT(datetime,
                   LEFT(ts, 8) + ' ' + SUBSTRING(ts, 10, 2) + ':' +
                   SUBSTRING(ts, 12, 2) + ':' + SUBSTRING(ts, 14, 2))
FROM t;
```

### Demo

Note that here I am building the timestamp `20220122 09:01:59` from the input string `20220122T090159`.